# run container as root user

Tags: docker, kubernetes, containers

Is there any way I can run container in k8s as root user or other user.
Like in docker

```
docker run --user <user> <image>
```

Is there any yaml configuration for running with

Answer (score 47):

As described in the [kubernetes docs](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/security-context/#set-the-security-context-for-a-container), you can set the security context for the container and set the `runAsUser` property as such:

```
 containers:
  - name: ...
    image: ...
    securityContext:
      runAsUser: 0
```

This will make the container execute internally as the root user.

Comment: Does it have to be 0 in runAsUser section?

Comment: 0 is the uid of the root user. You can use the id of the user that you want if you want something different than root.

Comment: so does the fsGroup default to 0 as well or do we need to mention it ?!

Comment: @Prathameshdhanawade the default is running under the root user, so above addition of `runAsUser: 0` has same effect as doing nothing, though it is more explicit.

Answer (score 2):

There are atleast 2 ways of setting as root user in a Pod.

`**Option1 - set runAsUser to 0.  Option2 - Do not include runAsUser in the definition. Below are 2 examples.**`

```
spec:
  containers:
  - command:
    - sleep
    - "4800"
    image: ubuntu
    imagePullPolicy: Always
    name: ubuntu
    resources: {}
    securityContext:
      capabilities:
        add:
        - SYS_TIME
      runAsUser: 0
```

k exec -it ubuntu-sleeper -- /bin/bash

```
root@ubuntu-sleeper:/# ps aux
USER       PID %CPU %MEM    VSZ   RSS TTY      STAT START   TIME COMMAND
root         1  0.0  0.0   2780  1032 ?        Ss   08:47   0:00 sleep 4800
root        66  0.0  0.0   4620  3848 pts/0    Ss   08:48   0:00 /bin/bash
root        74  0.0  0.0   7052  1580 pts/0    R+   08:48   0:00 ps aux

spec:
  containers:
  - command:
    - sleep
    - "4800"
    image: ubuntu
    imagePullPolicy: Always
    name: ubuntu
    resources: {}
    securityContext:
      capabilities:
        add:
        - SYS_TIME
```

k exec -it ubuntu-sleeper -- /bin/bash

```
root@ubuntu-sleeper:/# ps aux
USER       PID %CPU %MEM    VSZ   RSS TTY      STAT START   TIME COMMAND
root         1  0.0  0.0   2780   992 ?        Ss   08:55   0:00 sleep 4800
root        63  0.0  0.0   4616  3716 pts/0    Ss   08:56   0:00 /bin/bash
root        72  0.0  0.0   7052  1648 pts/0    R+   08:56   0:00 ps aux
```